# How does one allow a subset of UNICODE codepoints in input validation?

Tags: validation, unicode, codepoint

I am creating a service that could "go international" to non-English speaking markets.  I do not want to restrict a username to the ASCII range of characters but would like to allow a user to specify their "natural" username.  OK, use UNICODE (and say UTF-8 as my username text encoding).

But!  I don't want users to create "non-name" usernames that contain "symbol" code points.  For instance, I don't want to allow a username like √√√√√√øøøøø.

Is there a list of "symbol" code points for UNICODE that I can check (perhaps with a regex) to accept/reject a given username?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode has several [categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), so you can easily exclude symbols. How exactly to do that depends on the language you are using. Some regex frameworks have that feature built-in, some don't.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea about this! That's perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose for my purposes I'll allow codepoints in any of these categories:

[Ll] Letter, Lowercase
[Lm] Letter, Modifier
[Lo] Letter, Other
[Lt] Letter, Titlecase
[Lu] Letter, Uppercase

Comment: Well, for example Perl supports a pseudo-category for regular expression called *IsWord*, which is defined as: Ll+Lu+Lt+Lo+Nd

Answer (score 0):

In Python (per [Input validation of free-form Unicode text in Python](https://ipsec.pl/python/2017/input-validation-free-form-unicode-text-python.html)):

```
def only_letters(s):
    """
    Returns True if the input text consists of letters and ideographs only, False otherwise.
    """
    for c in s:
        cat = unicodedata.category(c)
        # Ll=lowercase, Lu=uppercase, Lo=ideographs
        if cat not in ('Ll','Lu','Lo'):
            return False
    return True

> only_letters('Bzdrężyło')
True
> only_letters('He7lo') # we don't allow digits here
False
```